# Mininet and ODL Ping issues using CLI

Tags: opendaylight, mininet

I am using mininet and ODL controller. Previously, when I was using the CLI to create topology and connect to my controller (which is installed on another virtual machine), it was pinging fine between all the hosts and life was good.

Now I'm not able to ping between hosts. Specifically when I build one switch with two hosts, because when I build 3 switches sometimes two hosts will ping each other.

I did h1 arp command on mininet and it was showing HardwareAddress incomplete and sometimes the iface is displaying:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJKS0.jpg)

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (for example for `R`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please [edit] your question to provide the computer output as text (format as code).

Comment: Thanks for responding the problem solved, I installed a new version of ODL controller which oxygen last release, but the problem didn't solve yet, after that I did an update to ubuntu 16.04, and problem solved I don't know how but it's working fine now it's pinging fine :)